# Ruby 1.9.2 how to install RMagick on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm currently upgrading an old rails app to use Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.2, and RMagick is the last gem I need to install.  However there doesn't seem to be any 1.9.2 downloads for Windows and the standard gem install RMagick doesn't work.

Could someone point me in the right direction on how to install this gem?

Comment: Late at the party. Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39513938/1903781) on how to install `rmagik` on windows 10.

Answer (score 42):

I just installed RMagick 2.13.1 successfully on Windows with Ruby v1.9.x !

Let me spill out the procedure, before I forget.

1. Install DevKit : https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit .
2. Install ImageMagick 6.6.x with windows installer with headers.
   NOTE: 
   -Do not install ImageMagick in a path which has spaces in it.
   The default path C:/Program Files/... will not work.
   Install it at a simpler path.
   -- Remove any older installations of ImageMagick and RMagick
3. Set the paths in Environment Variables:

   set DFImageMagick environment variable to where ImageMagick is installed
   set PATH=%DFImageMagick%;%PATH% (if you don't already have it in PATH)
   set CPATH=%DFImageMagick%\include;%CPATH%
   set LIBRARY_PATH=%DFImageMagick%\lib;%LIBRARY_PATH%
4. Install RMagick gem : 
   gem install rmagick 
   This should say, 
   Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
   Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
   After some time, Successfully installed rmagick 2.13.1
5. Verify installation:

   A. convert -version 
   this should give the ImageMagick installation version
   B. gem list --local should list rmagick 2.13.1
   Alternative: in irb, try 
   require 'rmagick' 
   it should return 'true'

Oh, I do like installations which complete in 5 steps.

Hope this works for you and others.

ref:

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/204353#new

http://www.waydotnet.com/blog/2010/02/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/#[link text](http://www.waydotnet.com/blog/2010/02/rmagick-on-ruby-1-9-1-i386-mingw32-work-d/#)

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. p.s. windows installers for ImageMagick are here http://www.imagemagick.com/www/binary-releases.html#windows

Comment: This solution also works with the latest ImageMagick (ImageMagick 6.7.0-6 2011-06-07 Q16). Thanks!

Comment: So far it has not worked for me, it says 'require': no such file to load -- RMagick2.so.  This crashes the Mongrel Server

Comment: @TravisPessetto I had the same problem, but I found the solution for problem. The [rmagick-FAQ](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#loaderror) recommend to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` not `LIBRARY_PATH` like in this description. With `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it worked fine for me.

Comment: I am still stuck, but I'm just going to chip in to say "WTF??? Software that can't be installed in a directory path containing spaces??? Is it 1993????"

Comment: Plain `gem install rmagick` doesn't work for me. It has to be `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q16/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q16/include` like Luis Lavena said in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6477787/196451)

Comment: RMagick no longer works with ImageMagick 6.8. See the GitHub wiki for detailed instructions https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki

Comment: looks like all the links to the Windows binaries on the ImageMagick site are dead (404).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't have to install DevKit if RailsInstaller or RubyInstaller has already done it for you.

Comment: 6 steps for me: I had to set `imagemagick_convert_command` explicitly in the configuration.yml.

Comment: Worked for me on Win764 & ImageMagick 6.8.7.0

Answer (score 10):

After some attempts, this finally worked for me:

1. Install DevKit : https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit
2. Install [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) (tick yes for headers in the installer) to a folder without spaces in its path (i used C:/ImageMagick)
3. Open up mingw (msys.bat in DevKit folder) -- and run `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick/include` (replace the two paths to account for your imagemagick path if needed)

Comment: Thanks for this version. It succeeded also for me - and there is no need to adapt (LD)LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: God bless you! I spent hours looking for the solution. I was missing step 3, more exactly I was running `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick/include` in cmd instead of msys.bat in DevKit folder

Answer (score 5):

I believe there are a few *gotchas* with RMagick and 1.9, as discussed in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/c837c4438d91208b) at RubyInstaller group.

However, [here](http://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/10/install-rmagick-on-mingw-and-msys.html) you can find a post describing the steps.

Other tutorials can be found in [our wiki](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Tutorials)

Hope that helps

Comment: The post describing the steps was what I needed, especially the `gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=c:/ImageMagick-Path/lib --with-opt-include=c:/ImageMagick-Path/include` part- that was the missing step from my attempts to install it.

Answer (score 4):

Srividya's solution also works with ImageMagick-6.7.0-8-Q16-windows-dll and RMagick 2.13.1.
Make sure you are using 32-bit version of ImageMagick if this doesn't work for you on 64-bit version of Windows.
I did, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me using ruby 2.0:

```
$ gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:/RailsInstaller/ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q8/lib --with-opt-include=c
:/RailsInstaller/ImageMagick-6.7.7-Q8/include
```

make sure to specify your own version of ImageMagick and the file path you installed it in & include the lib folder on the command

Answer (score 0):

- Installed rmagick in c:\rmagick.. folder

And tried the following command and it works:

```
gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-lib=C:\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\lib --with-opt-include=c:\ImageMagick-6.8.6-Q16\include
```