# Problems installing RMagick

Tags: ruby, windows, installation, rubygems, rmagick

I know there are already some questions and extensive answers about RMagick for Ruby 1.9.x, but I still have problems installing it.

I am working with the Ruby-Aptana Plugin for Eclipse and I have already installed the DevKit. I have tried to install RMagick as follows:

1. I have downloaded and installed ImageMagick 6.7.6-5-Q16-windows-dll.exe from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) in C:/ImageMagick6.7.6-5-Q16-windows-dll.exe
   Hope this is that one with headers?
2. Then I set the environment variables, but I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried that in windows control panel --> system --> advanced settings --> environment variables --> system variables. There I set:

PATH --> values: C:\Ruby192\bin and C:\ImageMagick-6.7.6-Q16

CPATH --> C:\ImageMagick-6.7.6-Q16\include

LIBRARY_PATH --> C:\ImageMagick-6.7.6-Q16\lib

3. I installed the rmagick gem: gem install rmagick

Unfortunately I still get the error:

```
  Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
  Buidling native extensions. This could take a while...
  ERROR: Error installing rmagick:
     ERROR: Error installing rmagick:
  
     c:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe  extconf.rb
  checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
  checking for stdint.h...*** extconf.rb failed***
  Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary 
  libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
```

I'm a Ruby-Starter and hope you respect this when answering my (perhaps silly) question.
Thank u all for you help!

Comment: Late at the party. Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39513938/1903781) on how to install `rmagik` on windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ditch RMagick altogether.

RMagick eats up a ton of memory. There are other ruby wrappers for ImageMagick out there that I have had an easier time using.

https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick

MiniMagick is pretty straightforward.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gem install win32-service --platform=mswin32
gem install rmagick --platform=mswin32
```

Comment: I have the same problem as described so I tried this. It didn't resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check also [Ruby 1.9.2 how to install RMagick on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451213/ruby-1-9-2-how-to-install-rmagick-on-windows)

In your step 2 you adapt `LIBRARY_PATH`. This worked not for me in the past (even if it is recommended in many manuals). The [rmagick-FAQ](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#loaderror) recommend to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` not `LIBRARY_PATH`. With `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` it worked fine for me.