# Gem Rmagick install error: extconf.rb:171:in ``': No such file or directory - convert -version (Errno::ENOE NT)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, imagemagick, rmagick

I get this error when installing rmagick, I have followed all kind of guides and get the same error every time. This time I have followed this guide: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEWAVlNCKhg&feature=youtu.be
:

```
   C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-include=C:/ImageMagick/Sou
    rceCode --with-opt-lib=C:/ImageMagick
    checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby
    extconf.rb:171:in ``': No such file or directory - convert -version (Errno::ENOE
    NT)
            from extconf.rb:171:in `<main>'


    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2
    .13.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick
    /gem_make.out

    c:\>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the error:

```
extconf.rb:171:in ``': No such file or directory - convert -version
(Errno::ENOENT)
```

it would appear that you don't have Imagemagick (or an equivalent) installed.  The main application in the Imagemagick suite is the `convert` binary.  If you're certain you *do* have it installed, then you should check that it's accessible in the `PATH`.

Comment: I think it is installed:     c:\ImageMagick>convert -version
    Version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-7 2012-04-20 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
    Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
    Features: OpenMP

Comment: Except you're running ruby from `C:/Ruby192/bin/`.  If you're in that directory, what happens when you try to run `convert -version`?

Comment: Then it is not recognised. c:\Ruby192\bin>convert -version
'convert' blev ikke genkendt som en intern eller ekstern kommando,
et program eller en batchfil.

Comment: Then you need to add `C:\ImageMagick` to your path.  See http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/configuration/how-can-i-add-a-new-folder-to-my-system-path- for how to do that (if you don't already know how).

Comment: I have added all the varibles in step 3 in this answer still get the same error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451213/ruby-1-9-2-how-to-install-rmagick-on-windows

Comment: The main test you need to concern yourself with is the one from my first comment on my answer: can you run `convert -version` from `C:\Ruby192\bin\`?  If no, then you didn't set your paths correctly.  If you can, then triple-check the error to see if you're actually getting the same error.

Comment: Yes I can do that: C:\Ruby192\bin>convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.6-7 2012-04-20 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP

But gives a loaderror in the console: C:\Rails\myapp>irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> require 'RMagick'
LoadError: no such file to load -- RMagick
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.r

Comment: You should make a new question for that, as it's a different error.

Answer (score 1):

First I thought I should set the environment variables in the system.

But setting these variables in the command view:

```
set DFImageMagick = C:\ImageMagick
set PATH=%DFImageMagick%;%PATH% (if you don't already have it in PATH)
set CPATH=%DFImageMagick%\include;%CPATH%
set LIBRARY_PATH=%DFImageMagick%\lib;%LIBRARY_PATH%
```

And then running the command `gem install rmagick`

And the gem was installed without any errors!

Comment: Helped this code: "set PATH=%DFImageMagick%;%PATH% (if you don't already have it in PATH)"