# Rmagick can't continue.I can't get this gem working on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

I am a beginner rails developer.I am trying to install Rmagick but i got these errors.On windows.

Installing rmagick 2.15.4 with native extensions

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4/ext/RMagick
C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160709-7156-1eqm5da.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:110:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version (Errno::ENOENT)
        from extconf.rb:110:in `configure_compile_options'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `initialize'
        from extconf.rb:517:in `new'
        from extconf.rb:517:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rmagick-2.15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/rmagick-2.15.4/gem_make.out
Using sqlite3 1.3.11
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using rdoc 4.2.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.8
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.6
Using mime-types 3.1
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.3.6.2
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using sprockets 3.6.2
Using haml 4.0.7
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.15.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.15.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

In case you migth ask, i  have imagemagick installed and i clicked the add the path option.What should i do?

Comment: Did you install DevKit too? Rmagick is difficult to install in Windows, but googling turns up a few guides.

Comment: Yes.I got devkit installed.I am sick of these errors.I cant use carrierwave to the fullest without this rmagick.I tried paperclip but it says "image has contents that are not reported to be" .So what should i do ?

Comment: Have you followed comments to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10306028/2116518)?

Comment: Please post the contents of `C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/rmagick-2.15.4/gem_make.out` to a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/) or a [GitLab snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/new) and provide a link to it. Thank you.