# How to install rmagick gem on Windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

How do I install rmagick gem for Windows XP? I already installed ImageMagick with the header files, and I installed RailsInstaller.org which comes with DevKit. I don't know where to look to fix these errors.

```
C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16>gem -v
1.8.16

C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16>path=%PATH%;C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16

C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16>identify
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.2-0 2013-01-24 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 ImageMagick Studio LLC

C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16>gem install rmagick
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2    .13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out



C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16>dir include
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is F8E5-EDB8

 Directory of C:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16\include

01/29/2013  04:33 PM    <DIR>          .
01/29/2013  04:33 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/29/2013  04:33 PM    <DIR>          magick
01/29/2013  04:33 PM    <DIR>          Magick++
09/05/2009  04:47 PM               419 Magick++.h
01/29/2013  04:33 PM    <DIR>          wand
```

Here is the contents of gem_make.out

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
Invalid drive specification.
Unable to get ImageMagick version
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
```

Here is the contents of extconf.rb

```
require "mkmf"
require "date"

RMAGICK_VERS = "2.13.1"
MIN_RUBY_VERS = "1.8.5"
MIN_RUBY_VERS_NO = MIN_RUBY_VERS.tr(".","").to_i
MIN_IM_VERS = "6.4.9"
MIN_IM_VERS_NO = MIN_IM_VERS.tr(".","").to_i



# Test for a specific value in an enum type
def have_enum_value(enum, value, headers=nil, &b)
  checking_for "#{enum}.#{value}" do
    if try_compile(<<"SRC", &b)
#{COMMON_HEADERS}
#{cpp_include(headers)}
/*top*/
int main() { #{enum} t = #{value}; t = t; return 0; }
SRC
      $defs.push(format("-DHAVE_ENUM_%s", value.upcase))
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end
end




# Test for multiple values of the same enum type
def have_enum_values(enum, values, headers=nil, &b)
  values.each do |value|
    have_enum_value(enum, value, headers, &b)
  end
end




def exit_failure(msg)
  Logging::message msg
  message msg+"\n"
  exit(1)
end




# Seems like lots of people have multiple versions of ImageMagick installed.
def check_multiple_imagemagick_versions()
   versions = []
   path = ENV['PATH'].split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)
   path.each do |dir|
      file = File.join(dir, "Magick-config")
      if File.executable? file
         vers = `#{file} --version`.chomp.strip
         prefix = `#{file} --prefix`.chomp.strip
         versions << [vers, prefix, dir]
      end
   end
   versions.uniq!
   if versions.size > 1
      msg = "\nWarning: Found more than one ImageMagick installation. This could cause problems at runtime.\n"
      versions.each do |vers, prefix, dir|
         msg << "         #{dir}/Magick-config reports version #{vers} is installed in #{prefix}\n"
      end
      msg << "Using #{versions[0][0]} from #{versions[0][1]}.\n\n"
      Logging::message msg
      message msg
   end
end


# Ubuntu (maybe other systems) comes with a partial installation of
# ImageMagick in the prefix /usr (some libraries, no includes, and no
# binaries). This causes problems when /usr/lib is in the path (e.g., using
# the default Ruby installation).
def check_partial_imagemagick_versions()
   prefix = config_string("prefix")
   matches = [
     prefix+"/lib/lib?agick*",
     prefix+"/include/ImageMagick",
     prefix+"/bin/Magick-config",
   ].map do |file_glob|
     Dir.glob(file_glob)
   end
   matches.delete_if { |arr| arr.empty? }
   if 0 < matches.length and matches.length < 3
      msg = "\nWarning: Found a partial ImageMagick installation. Your operating system likely has some built-in ImageMagick libraries but not all of ImageMagick. This will most likely cause problems at both compile and runtime.\nFound partial installation at: "+prefix+"\n"
      Logging::message msg
      message msg
   end
end



if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin/
  abort <<END_MSWIN
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| This rmagick gem is for use only on Linux, BSD, OS X, and similar systems  |
| that have a gnu or similar toolchain installed. The rmagick-win32 gem is a |
| pre-compiled version of RMagick bundled with ImageMagick for use on        |
| Microsoft Windows systems. The rmagick-win32 gem is available on RubyForge.|
| See http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html for more information.    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
END_MSWIN
end




unless checking_for("Ruby version >= #{MIN_RUBY_VERS}") do
  version = RUBY_VERSION.tr(".","").to_i
  version >= MIN_RUBY_VERS_NO
end
  exit_failure "Can't install RMagick #{RMAGICK_VERS}. Ruby #{MIN_RUBY_VERS} or later required.\n"
end




# Magick-config is not available on Windows
if RUBY_PLATFORM !~ /mswin|mingw/

  # Check for compiler. Extract first word so ENV['CC'] can be a program name with arguments.
  cc = (ENV["CC"] or Config::CONFIG["CC"] or "gcc").split(' ').first
  unless find_executable(cc)
    exit_failure "No C compiler found in ${ENV['PATH']}. See mkmf.log for details."
  end

  # Check for Magick-config
  unless find_executable("Magick-config")
    exit_failure "Can't install RMagick #{RMAGICK_VERS}. Can't find Magick-config in #{ENV['PATH']}\n"
  end

  check_multiple_imagemagick_versions()
  check_partial_imagemagick_versions()

  # Ensure minimum ImageMagick version
  unless checking_for("ImageMagick version >= #{MIN_IM_VERS}")  do
    version = `Magick-config --version`.chomp.tr(".","").to_i
    version >= MIN_IM_VERS_NO
  end
    exit_failure "Can't install RMagick #{RMAGICK_VERS}. You must have ImageMagick #{MIN_IM_VERS} or later.\n"
  end




  $magick_version = `Magick-config --version`.chomp

  # Ensure ImageMagick is not configured for HDRI
  unless checking_for("HDRI disabled version of ImageMagick") do
    not (`Magick-config --version`["HDRI"])
  end
    exit_failure "\nCan't install RMagick #{RMAGICK_VERS}."+
           "\nRMagick does not work when ImageMagick is configured for High Dynamic Range Images."+
           "\nDon't use the --enable-hdri option when configuring ImageMagick.\n"
  end

  # Save flags
  $CFLAGS     = ENV["CFLAGS"].to_s   + " " + `Magick-config --cflags`.chomp
  $CPPFLAGS   = ENV["CPPFLAGS"].to_s + " " + `Magick-config --cppflags`.chomp
  $LDFLAGS    = ENV["LDFLAGS"].to_s  + " " + `Magick-config --ldflags`.chomp
  $LOCAL_LIBS = ENV["LIBS"].to_s     + " " + `Magick-config --libs`.chomp

elsif RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw/  # mingw

  `convert -version` =~ /Version: ImageMagick (\d+\.\d+\.\d+)-\d+ /
  abort "Unable to get ImageMagick version" unless $1
  $magick_version = $1
  $LOCAL_LIBS = '-lCORE_RL_magick_ -lX11'

else  # mswin

  `convert -version` =~ /Version: ImageMagick (\d+\.\d+\.\d+)-\d+ /
  abort "Unable to get ImageMagick version" unless $1
  $magick_version = $1
  $CFLAGS = "-W3"
  $CPPFLAGS = %Q{-I"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2\\Include" -I"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-#{$magick_version}-Q8\\include"}
  # The /link option is required by the Makefile but causes warnings in the mkmf.log file.
  $LDFLAGS = %Q{/link /LIBPATH:"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2\\Lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-#{$magick_version}-Q8\\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\\ruby\\lib"}
  $LOCAL_LIBS = 'CORE_RL_magick_.lib X11.lib'

end



#headers = %w{assert.h ctype.h errno.h float.h limits.h math.h stdarg.h stddef.h stdint.h stdio.h stdlib.h string.h time.h}
headers = %w{assert.h ctype.h stdio.h stdlib.h math.h time.h}
headers << "stdint.h" if have_header("stdint.h")  # defines uint64_t
headers << "sys/types.h" if have_header("sys/types.h")


if have_header("wand/MagickWand.h")
   headers << "wand/MagickWand.h"
else
   exit_failure "\nCan't install RMagick #{RMAGICK_VERS}. Can't find MagickWand.h."
end



if RUBY_PLATFORM !~ /mswin|mingw/

  unless have_library("MagickCore", "InitializeMagick", headers) || have_library("Magick", "InitializeMagick", headers) || have_library("Magick++","InitializeMagick",headers)
    exit_failure "Can't install RMagick #{RMAGICK_VERS}. " +
           "Can't find the ImageMagick library or one of the dependent libraries. " +
           "Check the mkmf.log file for more detailed information.\n"
  end
end


have_func("snprintf", headers)
  ["AcquireImage",                   # 6.4.1
   "AffinityImage",                  # 6.4.3-6
   "AffinityImages",                 # 6.4.3-6
   "AutoGammaImageChannel",          # 6.5.5-1
   "AutoLevelImageChannel",          # 6.5.5-1
   "BlueShiftImage",                 # 6.5.4-3
   "ConstituteComponentTerminus",    # 6.5.7-9
   "DeskewImage",                    # 6.4.2-5
   "EncipherImage",                  # 6.3.8-6
   "EqualizeImageChannel",           # 6.3.6-9
   "FloodfillPaintImage",            # 6.3.7
   "FunctionImageChannel",           # 6.4.8-8
   "GetAuthenticIndexQueue",         # 6.4.5-6
   "GetAuthenticPixels",             # 6.4.5-6
   "GetImageAlphaChannel",           # 6.3.9-2
   "GetVirtualPixels",               # 6.4.5-6
   "LevelImageColors",               # 6.4.2
   "LevelColorsImageChannel",        # 6.5.6-4
   "LevelizeImageChannel",           # 6.4.2
   "LiquidRescaleImage",             # 6.3.8-2
   "MagickLibAddendum",              # 6.5.9-1
   "OpaquePaintImageChannel",        # 6.3.7-10
   "QueueAuthenticPixels",           # 6.4.5-6
   "RemapImage",                     # 6.4.4-0
   "RemoveImageArtifact",            # 6.3.6
   "SelectiveBlurImageChannel",      # 6.5.0-3
   "SetImageAlphaChannel",           # 6.3.6-9
   "SetImageArtifact",               # 6.3.6
   "SetMagickMemoryMethods",         # 6.4.1
   "SparseColorImage",               # 6.3.6-?
   "SyncAuthenticPixels",            # 6.4.5-6
   "TransparentPaintImage",          # 6.3.7-10
   "TransparentPaintImageChroma"     # 6.4.5-6
   ].each do |func|
    have_func(func, headers)
  end




checking_for("QueryMagickColorname() new signature")  do
  if try_compile(<<"SRC")
#{COMMON_HEADERS}
#{cpp_include(headers)}
/*top*/
int main() {
  MagickBooleanType okay;
  Image *image;
  MagickPixelPacket *color;
  char *name;
  ExceptionInfo *exception;
  okay = QueryMagickColorname(image, color, SVGCompliance, name, exception);
  return 0;
  }
SRC
    $defs.push("-DHAVE_NEW_QUERYMAGICKCOLORNAME")
    true
  else
    false
  end
end




have_struct_member("Image", "type", headers)          # ???
have_struct_member("DrawInfo", "kerning", headers)    # 6.4.7-8
have_struct_member("DrawInfo", "interline_spacing", headers)   # 6.5.5-8
have_struct_member("DrawInfo", "interword_spacing", headers)   # 6.4.8-0
have_type("DitherMethod", headers)                    # 6.4.2
have_type("MagickFunction", headers)                  # 6.4.8-8
have_type("ImageLayerMethod", headers)                # 6.3.6 replaces MagickLayerMethod
have_type("long double", headers)
#have_type("unsigned long long", headers)
#have_type("uint64_t", headers)
#have_type("__int64", headers)
#have_type("uintmax_t", headers)
#check_sizeof("unsigned long", headers)
#check_sizeof("Image *", headers)


have_enum_values("AlphaChannelType", ["CopyAlphaChannel",                    # 6.4.3-7
                                      "BackgroundAlphaChannel"], headers)    # 6.5.2-5
have_enum_values("CompositeOperator", ["BlurCompositeOp",                    # 6.5.3-7
                                       "DistortCompositeOp",                 # 6.5.3-10
                                       "LinearBurnCompositeOp",              # 6.5.4-3
                                       "LinearDodgeCompositeOp",             # 6.5.4-3
                                       "MathematicsCompositeOp",             # 6.5.4-3
                                       "PegtopLightCompositeOp",             # 6.5.4-3
                                       "PinLightCompositeOp",                # 6.5.4-3
                                       "VividLightCompositeOp"], headers)    # 6.5.4-3
have_enum_values("CompressionType", ["DXT1Compression",                      # 6.3.9-3
                                     "DXT3Compression",                      # 6.3.9-3
                                     "DXT5Compression",                      # 6.3.9-3
                                     "ZipSCompression",                      # 6.5.5-4
                                     "PizCompression",                       # 6.5.5-4
                                     "Pxr24Compression",                     # 6.5.5-4
                                     "B44Compression",                       # 6.5.5-4
                                     "B44ACompression"], headers)            # 6.5.5-4

have_enum_values("DistortImageMethod", ["BarrelDistortion",                  # 6.4.2-5
                                        "BarrelInverseDistortion",           # 6.4.3-8
                                        "BilinearForwardDistortion",         # 6.5.1-2
                                        "BilinearReverseDistortion",         # 6.5.1-2
                                        "DePolarDistortion",                 # 6.4.2-6
                                        "PolarDistortion",                   # 6.4.2-6
                                        "PolynomialDistortion",              # 6.4.2-4
                                        "ShepardsDistortion"], headers)      # 6.4.2-4
have_enum_value("DitherMethod", "NoDitherMethod", headers)                   # 6.4.3
have_enum_values("FilterTypes", ["KaiserFilter",                             # 6.3.6
                                 "WelshFilter",                              # 6.3.6-4
                                 "ParzenFilter",                             # 6.3.6-4
                                 "LagrangeFilter",                           # 6.3.7-2
                                 "BohmanFilter",                             # 6.3.7-2
                                 "BartlettFilter",                           # 6.3.7-2
                                 "SentinelFilter"], headers)                 # 6.3.7-2
have_enum_values("MagickEvaluateOperator", ["PowEvaluateOperator",           # 6.4.1-9
                                           "LogEvaluateOperator",            # 6.4.2
                                           "ThresholdEvaluateOperator",      # 6.4.3
                                           "ThresholdBlackEvaluateOperator", # 6.4.3
                                           "ThresholdWhiteEvaluateOperator", # 6.4.3
                                           "GaussianNoiseEvaluateOperator",  # 6.4.3
                                           "ImpulseNoiseEvaluateOperator",   # 6.4.3
                                           "LaplacianNoiseEvaluateOperator", # 6.4.3
                                           "MultiplicativeNoiseEvaluateOperator", # 6.4.3
                                           "PoissonNoiseEvaluateOperator",   # 6.4.3
                                           "UniformNoiseEvaluateOperator",   # 6.4.3
                                           "CosineEvaluateOperator",         # 6.4.8-5
                                           "SineEvaluateOperator",           # 6.4.8-5
                                           "AddModulusEvaluateOperator"],    # 6.4.8-5
                                                                 headers)
have_enum_values("MagickFunction", ["ArcsinFunction",                        # 6.5.2-8
                                    "ArctanFunction",                        # 6.5.2-8
                                    "PolynomialFunction",                    # 6.4.8-8
                                    "SinusoidFunction"], headers)            # 6.4.8-8
have_enum_values("ImageLayerMethod", ["FlattenLayer",                           # 6.3.6-2
                                      "MergeLayer",                             # 6.3.6
                                      "MosaicLayer",                            # 6.3.6-2
                                      "TrimBoundsLayer" ], headers)             # 6.4.3-8
have_enum_values("VirtualPixelMethod", ["HorizontalTileVirtualPixelMethod",     # 6.4.2-6
                                        "VerticalTileVirtualPixelMethod",       # 6.4.2-6
                                        "HorizontalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod", # 6.5.0-1
                                        "VerticalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod",   # 6.5.0-1
                                        "CheckerTileVirtualPixelMethod"],       # 6.5.0-1
                                                                 headers)


# Now test Ruby 1.9.0 features.
headers = ["ruby.h"]
if have_header("ruby/io.h")
   headers << "ruby/io.h"
else
   headers << "rubyio.h"
end

have_func("rb_frame_this_func", headers)

# Miscellaneous constants
$defs.push("-DRUBY_VERSION_STRING=\"ruby #{RUBY_VERSION}\"")
$defs.push("-DRMAGICK_VERSION_STRING=\"RMagick #{RMAGICK_VERS}\"")

create_header()
# Prior to 1.8.5 mkmf duplicated the symbols on the command line and in the
# extconf.h header. Suppress that behavior by removing the symbol array.
$defs = []

# Force re-compilation if the generated Makefile changed.
$config_h = "Makefile rmagick.h"

create_makefile("RMagick2")


SUMMARY = <<"END_SUMMARY"


#{"=" * 70}
#{DateTime.now.strftime("%a %d%b%y %T")}
This installation of RMagick #{RMAGICK_VERS} is configured for
Ruby #{RUBY_VERSION} (#{RUBY_PLATFORM}) and ImageMagick #{$magick_version}
#{"=" * 70}


END_SUMMARY

Logging::message SUMMARY
message SUMMARY
```

This is the contents of mkmf.log

```
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... -------------------- yes

--------------------
```

I also have Cygwin and tried there, but encountered a different ruby related error. I can see a few errors, like 'Invalid drive specification', but I don't know where that is coming from.

Comment: Late at the party. Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39513938/1903781) on how to install `rmagik` on windows 10.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

RMagic won't work with ImageMagic 6.8. I updated the RMagick Github wiki with detailed instructions.

https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki

There I found gems (haha) such as

> If ImageMagick isn't first in your system path, you'll get an "Invalid
>   drive specification" error when extconf.rb tries to identify the
>   ImageMagick version.

and

```
gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="[path to ImageMagick]"'
```

(Obvious, huh?)

I believe RMagick is a dead project. There hasn't been a commit for 2 years!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using rmagick-win32:

http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#win

Comment: That's for 2.12. I was just now able to install 2.12. What if I need 2.13.1? `rmagick-win32 2.12.0 binary gem for Ruby 1.8.6 October 4, 2009`

Comment: @Chloe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451213/ruby-1-9-2-how-to-install-rmagick-on-windows, http://www.linuxdistrocommunity.com/videos/?user=SysAdmGirl&id=gEWAVlNCKhg, http://www.josephwahba.com/2012/01/install-rmagick-gem-on-windows-7/, etc.

Comment: Thanks. That's a lot to try. I found https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki and tried `gem install rmagick -- '--with-opt-dir="c:\RailsInstaller\ImageMagick-6.8.2-Q16"'` but now it failed with a compile error http://pastebin.com/j4vM5kLa

Comment: I found the answer and updated the wiki! Thanks! https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki

Answer (score 0):

try this video, it goes through the installation process for window 7. I followed the steps and it worked for me.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEWAVlNCKhg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Start Command Prompt in Administrator mode.
Set CPATH and LIBRARY_PATH environment variables to point respectively to ImageMagick installation directory include and lib subdirectories (so the DevKit will find them at build time)

> set CPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q16\include
>   set LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.9-Q16\lib

Then start a new command prompt and

> gem install rmagick

This worked for me!
See the result in http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_rmagick_gem_on_Windows