# How install rmagick in windows XP with ruby 1.9.3

Tags: windows, webkit, imagemagick, rmagick, ruby-1.9.3

Generally installation Ruby environment on Windows is BAD and STUPID idea!!!
Think well 1000 times before you do it!!!

My environment:

- windows XP (x32)
- ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32]
- DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx
- ImageMagick-6.8.8-2-Q8-x64-static.exe

I'm using this manual: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

I did more than 3 attempts to install it! 
It's easier and better to buy new laptop or install Linux on your machine!!!

After 4 hours of pain and suffering I was fortunate to run 'bundle install' successful.
Incidentally, I recommend:

1. install ruby to C:/ruby193  ( not into 'Program Files' !!! )
2. install devkit to C:/DevKit ( not into 'Program Files' !!! )

I don't understand WTF is going on with this. And now I have new error :)
This is a magic problem with ImageMagik ( I think Satan himself wrote this program! )
Now I can't install rmagick, cause of some problem of ruby,devkit, ImageMagik or rmagik.

I see this error, when run:

`gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2' -- '--with-opt-dir="C:\ImageMagick"'`

```
======================================================================
Tue 14Jan14 12:31:38
This installation of RMagick 2.13.2 is configured for
Ruby 1.9.3 (i386-mingw32) and ImageMagick 6.8.8
======================================================================

make
generating RMagick2-i386-mingw32.def
compiling rmagick.c
In file included from rmagick.c:13:0:
rmagick.h:81:2: error: #error Specified QuantumDepth is not supported.
rmagick.c: In function 'Magick_colors':
rmagick.c:42:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'GetColorInfoList' from incompatible pointer ty
C:\ImageMagick\include/magick/color.h:75:5: note: expected 'size_t *' but argument is of type
rmagick.c: In function 'Magick_fonts':
rmagick.c:90:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'GetTypeInfoList' from incompatible pointer typ
C:\ImageMagick\include/magick/type.h:98:5: note: expected 'size_t *' but argument is of type '
rmagick.c: In function 'Magick_init_formats':
rmagick.c:178:5: warning: passing argument 2 of 'GetMagickInfoList' from incompatible pointer
C:\ImageMagick\include/magick/magick.h:129:5: note: expected 'size_t *' but argument is of typ
make: *** [rmagick.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for insp
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

After few hours I understood that, I face this problem, 
cause when installing ImageMagik I forget to set one of checkboxses:

[image]

And now I see new error type in my terminal:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Bogdan>gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2' -- '--with-opt-dir="C:\ImageMagick"'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-dir="C:\ImageMagick"
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:194:in `'
```

What is it and how can I fix it? 
Please, help me

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow!!! This is the some kind of comedy,
 but I uninstall ImageMagick-6.8.8 and install ImageMagick-6.6.7.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Bogdan>gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2' -- '--with-opt-dir="C:\ImageMagick"'
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rmagick-2.13.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for rmagick-2.13.2...
```

SUCCESSFULLY INSTALLED RMAGICK-2.13.2 !!!!!!

Comment: Download exe files from http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/