# RMagick build on Windows fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, rmagick

I am trying to build gem install the rmagick gem on a Windows 8.1 machine with railsinstaller installed. I followed this guide: [Ruby 1.9.2 how to install RMagick on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451213/ruby-1-9-2-how-to-install-rmagick-on-windows)

On the step 4 gem install I get an error (as it seems compiling works and there's something wrong when linking):

```
compiling rmutil.c
linking shared-object RMagick2.so
rmagick.o: In function `Magick_colors':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rmagick-2.13.2\ext\RMagick/rmagick.c:40: undefined reference to `GetExceptionInfo'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rmagick-2.13.2\ext\RMagick/rmagick.c:42: undefined reference to `GetColorInfoList'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rmagick-2.13.2\ext\RMagick/rmagick.c:44: undefined reference to `DestroyExceptionInfo'
rmagick.o: In function `Magick_fonts':
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rmagick-2.13.2\ext\RMagick/rmagick.c:89: undefined reference to `GetExceptionInfo'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rmagick-2.13.2\ext\RMagick/rmagick.c:90: undefined reference to `GetTypeInfoList'
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rmagick-2.13.2\ext\RMagick/rmagick.c:92: undefined reference to `DestroyExceptionInfo'
rmagick.o: In function `Magick_init_formats':
```

And so on for many (I assume all) magick functions.

Any Idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the 32bit installation instead of the 64bit. Thanks to the good folks of Rubyinstaller at Google Groups to point me in the right direction.